# Rails query interface is not making some associations in Rails 5.1 with API option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've started to transfer an old application to a new Rails application. First, i've created it with Rails 5.0, taking the same database I was using in production.

One of my associations is like:

```
class Conta < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conta_cooperados, foreign_key: :id_conta
end  


class ContaCooperado < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conta, foreign_key: :id_conta
end
```

If I make a query like:

```
Conta.first.conta_cooperados
```

I will have the informations I wanted, and it will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT `conta_cooperado`.* FROM `conta_cooperado` WHERE `conta_cooperado`.`id_conta` = 1
```

As you can see, everything was working very well, but for some reasons I've decided to create a new application with Rails 5.1 and API option enabled.
And now, when I run the same query, the following SQL is generated:

```
SELECT  `conta_cooperado`.* FROM `conta_cooperado` WHERE `conta_cooperado`.`conta_cooperado` = NULL
```

And this one doesn't bring the expected result, because the `'conta_cooperado' . 'conta_cooperado' = NULL` part is wrong.

I don't know if this happens because I'm using Rails 5.1 instead 5.0, or if because I'm using the api mode.

**UPDATE**:

I just upgraded my Rails 5.0 application to 5.1 version, and, if until this upgrade everything was working, now I'm having the same problem. So, this situation happens only on 5.1 version of Rails. Is there a bug in this version?

Comment: table have  id_conta field ?

Comment: Yes, it does. My Rails 5.0 application is accessing the same database and everything is working well.

Comment: Can you access `Conta.first` in rails console ?

Comment: I do. It brings the expected information. I can also access ContaCooperado.first in rails console and it works.

Comment: And if i access ContaCooperado.first.conta, i have the same problem

Comment: Strange !! May be problem is in your association. may be. not sure

Comment: @ebfjunior I am experiencing the same issue with an api-only rails application that is currently running fine on Rails 5.0.5 but when I upgrade to 5.1.3 I see exactly the same issue as you. Did you figure out what the problem was?